# Files will corrupt when send by php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I use [this php mailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php4/0.90/) 
every things are O.k. but when I attach a file, corrupted file receive in destination email. for example when I send a pdf file receiver can't open it.

and this is my code in using phpmailer:

```
$target_path = "upload_files/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['attach']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

} else{

}

//eupload file end

require_once 'phpmailer/phpmailer.inc.php';
$mail             = new PHPMailer(); 
$body = $message;
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $fname." ".$lname);

$mail->FromName = $fname." ".$lname;
$mail->From = $email;    

$mail->AddAddress("email address", "some one");

$mail->Subject    = "something";

$mail->body = $body;

$mail->AddAttachment($target_path); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: Could you show some relevant!! code, now we have to guess what goes wrong.

Comment: @Tarilo What you want? corrupted file? If you want I can upload corrupted file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHPMailer have critical errors [try it](https://nodeload.github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/zip/master)

Answer (score 1):

Must be your Header include file's are wrong
becouse this is the basic mistake in attachments

```
$headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";
```

:P

Comment: Size of receive file is more than original :D

Comment: this how the message body

$message="
  
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message_body

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";